# glutTimerFunc problem

Tags: glut

I use `Glut` to make a simple animation. In the main function, `glutTimerFunc(TIMERMSECS, animate, 0)` is called. The two pieces of codes generate the same graphic.

```
const int TIMERMSECS = 20;
float animation_time = 0;
const float  animation_step = .5;
```

**Method 1:**

```
   void animate(int t){
        float time_elapsed = TIMERMSECS/1000.0;
        float current_step = animation_step* time_elapsed;
        glutTimerFunc(TIMERMSECS, animate, 0);
        if(current_step < animation_step*2) 
                animation_time += current_step;
        glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

**Method 2:**

```
   void animate(int t){
        float time_elapsed = TIMERMSECS/1000.0;
        float current_step = animation_step* time_elapsed;      
        if(current_step < animation_step*2) 
                animation_time += current_step;
        glutPostRedisplay();
       glutTimerFunc(TIMERMSECS, animate, 0);
}
```

The only difference between them is the position of `glutTimerFunc`. For `Method 1`, it looks like a recursive that will never reach the end of `animate()`function. But why does that still work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`glutTimerFunc` will not *immediately* call the timer function under any circumstances. Even if the time is 0. It always waits for the message processing loop, and even then it will only call the requested function when all other message processing has completed. That way, important messages like "repaint window" and "resize window" still get processed.

In general, you should not rely on the timer function being particularly accurate.

Comment: Do you mean `glutTimerFunc` begins to count the time `TIMERMSECS` after completing `glutPostRedisplay()` or `resize window`?

Comment: @Sean: It may. It may not. It's not really relevant, since GLUT doesn't make any guarantees on how accurate the timer function is. What matters is that window message processing will always happen, no matter how many timer functions you try to do. Whether glutPostRedisplay is part of that, I can't say.

Comment: Thanks, does the postion of `glutTimerFunc` affect the results. I mean putting this function at the beginning or at the middle could generate the same results?

Comment: @Sean: No. It's just a marker, used to let GLUT's message loop know that it should do some timing stuff when it runs out of real messages to process. Message processing is _not_ threaded or asynchronous.