# Timer Function in glut

Tags: c, opengl, glut

I want to display elapsed time on the screen and I want to reset the timer when I reset it.

How to get elapsed time ? and can we display integer on the screen?

Comment: Usually OP should post some of their code, and prove some minimal effort on their side...

Comment: Check that to take some ideas : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7210238/gluttimerfunc-problem

Answer (score 1):

freeglut has helper functions for time [glutTimerFunc](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/docs/api.php) and for displaying [fonts](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/docs/api.php#FontRendering).

Regardless from glut, the problem of computing elapsed time or rendering characters as bitmaps are very generic computer science tasks.